# How to make a 'cancel' button not trigger the forms validation?

Tags: jquery, validation

How to make a 'cancel' button not trigger the forms validation?

I'm using asp.net MVC with the jquery validation plugin.

Comment: Can you post your markup? Unless the form is submitting...it shouldn't be validating.

Answer (score 1):

Simply give it a `cancel` class:

```
<input type="submit" class="cancel" value="Submit without validation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the validation group of the elements you're validating, as well as the buttons. http://www.dotnet-guide.com/validationgroups.html

Answer (score 0):

Validation? Do you mean submission? If you want to cancel a form's submission, you have to return false on the form's submit event. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bzz4J/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an html5 'button' tag, add the type="button" attribute. This indicates that the behavior is not to 'submit' the form which is the default behavior and what is causing the validation to fire.

```
<button id="cancel" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='./'">Cancel</button>
```